# Missing information when scraping data in grafana using prometheus and minikube

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, minikube

I am trying to use prometheus and grafana to get information like cluster cpu usage, cluster memory usage and pod cpu usage in my kubernetes cluster. I am using minikube in wsl2. I am using following commands to get everything up and running:

To start minikube:

`$ minikube start`

To add repo and install prometheus:

`$ helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts`

`$ helm repo update`

`$ helm install prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus`

To create a nodeport on the port 9090:

`$ kubectl expose service prometheus-server --type=NodePort --target-port=9090 --name=prometheus-server-ext`

To access prometheus server outside minikube:

`$ minikube service prometheus-server-ext`
[image]

Adding grafana report and installing with helm:

`$ helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts`

`$ helm repo update`

`$ helm install grafana grafana/grafana`

To create a nodeport on the port 3000 :

`$ kubectl expose service grafana --type=NodePort --target-port=3000 --name=grafana-ext`

To access grafana server outside minikube:

`$ minikube service grafana-ext`

To get decode and get password to grafana(username:admin):

`$ kubectl get secret --namespace default grafana -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode ; echo`

Then I add a data source with type prometheus and the URL seen above: https://192.168.49.2:30988.
[image]

Until here everything works as expected. Then I import two different dashboards with the id "6417" and "12740". I then get the following dashboards:

[image]

and

[image]

My question is why do I only see the number of pods and cluster memory usage, but no cpu usage of pods or the cluster? It seems like there is a lot of information missing.

Here is the JSON code for dashboard with id 6417: https://pastebin.com/ywrT2qmQ

Here is the JSON code for dashboard with id 12740: https://pastebin.com/2neEzESu

I get the dashboards by using the id's 6417 and 12740 and importing it. Check image below:
[image]

Comment: You are going too fast, first you should check whether ElasticSearch has indexed that data you are looking for, with the info you provide we can not tell. That supposing this specific helm is using ElasticSearch for data indexing.

Comment: Hi `Adam Röhr` it seems that there is some config mismatch in the dashboards which you have imported. Instead of screenshots can you provide us with the json code of these two dashboards for further debugging also send us the links from which you have imported these dashboards for replication purpose.

Comment: Hi! I added the JSON code you asked.

Comment: @AdamRöhr from the Json files I could find that there are few UID values that are hard coded can you try this official dashboard once.. https://github.com/grafana/kubernetes-app

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni it has been deprecated..